# Solidity multiplication always resulting in 0

Tags: solidity, safemath

I'm trying to pay royalties from a contract to multiple wallets, however the multiplication is always sending me to 0.

> ```
> function withdraw_to_taxman() public view returns (uint256){
>     uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
>     uint256 withdraw_amount = balance * _tax_rate;
>     return (withdraw_amount);
> }
> ```

I'm writing this function to test how much I will withdraw, and then I would divide by 100 to get the actual withdrawal amount given that _tax_rate is a %.
This withdraw_amount always returns 0, and I'm not sure why
tax_rate is a uint256 that I am testing at the value of 1
I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does your contract have a balance?

I tried the follwing code and it worked for me:

```js
contract Contract {

    uint256 public _tax_rate = 1;

    function withdraw_to_taxman() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        uint256 withdraw_amount = balance * _tax_rate;
        return (withdraw_amount);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

}
```

I sent `5 wei` to the `receive() external payable` function so the balance of my contract is `5 wei`. The `_tax_rate` value is `1`, and when I called the `withdraw_to_taxman` function it returns `5`.

I deployed it and verified it on Rinkeby so you can play around with it:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x83E6C7707B8610b32157e8897CEd5C8375F5C04F#readContract

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x83E6C7707B8610b32157e8897CEd5C8375F5C04F#writeContract

I sent `0.000531 ether` and set the `tax_rate` to `3` and `withdraw_to_taxman` returns: `1593000000000000`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, but I'm still getting the error. I posted my full code here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135122/unable-to-withdraw-to-multiple-wallets-if-money-is-in-the-contract