# Unable to withdraw to multiple wallets IF money is in the contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721, safemath

This withdraw function works perfectly fine if there is 0 ethereum in the contract; however, the minute there is ethereum (I have been testing sending 0.04 ethereum), the withdraw function breaks. I assume it's a problem with solidity integer multiplication, but I'm not sure.

The goal here is to be able to set a "tax rate" on withdrawals, where a % of the withdrawal goes to the "tax man." Right now I have it set to 1%.

I appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you!

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract TestWithdraw is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _tax_rate = 1;
    address private _tax_man = 0xf9DEB97CcA539576CD582A785465eB9088f36696;


    constructor() ERC721('assetName', 'asset') 
    {
    }
    function recieve_money() public payable {

    }

    function withdraw_to_me() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        uint256 local_tax = 100 - _tax_rate;
        uint256 new_balance = balance * local_tax;
        return (new_balance);
    }
    function withdraw_to_taxman() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        uint256 withdraw_amount = balance * _tax_rate;
        return (withdraw_amount);
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdraw_to_me());
        payable(_tax_man).transfer(withdraw_to_taxman());
    }

}
```

Comment: The contract works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your `local_tax` is expressed as a percentage ranging from 0-100. You multiplied the `balance` by this number, but forgot to adjust for that it is a `percentage`, so you should divide by 100 afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to transfer out more ether than your contract has. This would fix it :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract TestWithdraw is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _tax_rate = 1;
    address private _tax_man = 0xf9DEB97CcA539576CD582A785465eB9088f36696;


    constructor() ERC721('assetName', 'asset') 
    {
    }
    function recieve_money() public payable {

    }

    function withdraw_to_me() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        uint256 local_tax = 100 - _tax_rate;
        uint256 new_balance = (balance * local_tax) / 100;
        return (new_balance);
    }
    function withdraw_to_taxman() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        uint256 withdraw_amount = (balance * _tax_rate) / 100;
        return (withdraw_amount);
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdraw_to_me());
        payable(_tax_man).transfer(withdraw_to_taxman());
    }

}
```

Also, you're overcomplicating this a bit. Something like :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TestWithdraw is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _tax_rate = 1;
    address private _tax_man = 0xf9DEB97CcA539576CD582A785465eB9088f36696;


    constructor() ERC721('assetName', 'asset') 
    {
    }
    function recieve_money() public payable {

    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        uint tax = (address(this).balance * tax_rate) / 100;
        payable(_tax_man).transfer(tax);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);    
    }

}
```

Would work as well, an be way more compact and elegant. Other side note, solidity style guide recommends using snake case over camel case, but  that's not really important haha